# WPF mainwindow controls binding property changed from another window

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I`m new to WPF and databinding so I stumbled on something.
I have created an app with vb.net where my MainWindow contains controls and a frame in which I load a page.
On the page I have a listview where the data is loaded from the database.

Now, I have created the Viewmodel and set up the properties to bind to the controls on the `Mainwindow` so I could set `IsEnabled` property to True or False through the `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

If I change the properties from the mainwindow code, is working. What I want to be able to do is when I click on an item on the page-listview to change the properties in the viewmodel and reflect it back to the UI of the `Mainwindow`.

I`v searched and could not find anything to help me out.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how can I achieve this or some directions to the right place where to find useful information or at least what needs to be used so I can research more of it?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

If the "Child" viewmodel has a reference to the "Parent" viewmodel it can update the properties on the parent and the INotifyPropertyChanged system should update the UI for you.

I'm not *entirely* sure this is what you are asking about though, your question is a little unclear.

Comment: For example: I have a button on the Mainwindow. That button IsEnabled property is binded to a property in the Viewmodel. How can i change the property in the viewmodel from another page or usercontrol and reflect it back to the mainwindow UI.

Comment: You can do that exactly as stated in my answer.  Give the other page or control a reference to the viewmodel and change the property via that reference.  As long as the property raises the `PropertyChanged` event of `INotifyPropertyChanged` properly, then the bindings will pick it up and update the UI.

Comment: Sorry.  I don't understand. How to reference that page to the viewmodel? Can you give me a small example?